# How to run Realtek 8153 Network Card on Huawei MateBook 14 2020 / CPU Ryzen 7 4800H

Tags: networking, 14.04, drivers, realtek, usb-modem

how to start the Realtek 8153 Network Card - in the Tp-Link UE300 Adapter.  I bought an Adpater Tp-Link UE300, I will give you the exact S / N: 221A054003411 / P / N: 0101502019 / Ver 3.0 Dear Linux Ubuntu Community.  Urgent need to run this Appter in Huawei MateBook 14 2020 with Ryzen 7 4800H CPU.  It informs that this Adapter won't run successfully on my Laptop, on a freshly installed system on an SSD Disk.  It informs that the Linux network search configurator - finds me the Lan network and the Wi-Fi network.  It informs that I installed this Linux without the network configuration, because the installer did not detect my Lan network card and Wi-Fi network card.

In addition, it was difficult for me to detect the network card / Wi-Fi adapter model in this Laptop model.

I am asking you for your support.  Please write back to me how after successfully installing Linux on the disk - should I follow to run the network configurator?  It informs that the configurator is turned on successfully, but I cannot log in to the Wi-Fi network - entering the Password.  It informs that when trying to configure the Lan network, there is a request for Authorization - by entering the Linux Administrative Password - still does not connect me to the Lan network in Linux.

**From 'Answer':** How to successfully check the correct model of Wi-Fi card / adapter in this Laptop? Please, indicate how to implement, successfully run the tool for reading the exact model of the network card / Wi-Fi adapter in the console.

Comment: Hello. If you are running 14.04 it is LONG past EOL and not supported on this site. Sorry.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/   *You've tagged an EOL/ESM release that is off-topic here*

Comment: Can you edit your question and add clearer details for the several times where you say *"it informs me"* -- please use the exact text/message verbatim. Also include the steps needed to reproduce these messages. Also define "it" -- are these outputs of commands you entered in your terminal? Are they from a particular application?  Adding these details will help us understand the problem and increase the likelihood we can answer